# Displaying data in table foreach loop

Tags: php, html, json, foreach, html-table

I am calling `github api` to list all the issues I have in my repo.
I want to list these issues in table form on my site...

However I cannot get the table going with my foreach loop.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP');

    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach ($data as $i) {
      // echo $i->number.";".$i->state.";".$i->title.";".$i->body."\n\r";
      echo "<tr><td>".$i->number."</td><td>".$i->state."</td><td>".$i->title."</td><td>".$i->body."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: where is the starting and ending html code of table?

Comment: can you please add the output of print_r($data);? So it will be simple to help you.

Comment: 1. (just as @RamSharma said) Where is the start and end of the table html ?
2. What is the result you get from that code ?

Comment: thanks gents @krishna helped me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing table tag. so try this

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP');
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues");
$data = json_decode($json);
echo "<table>"   ;
foreach ($data as $i)
{
//    echo $i->number.";".$i->state.";".$i->title.";".$i->body."\n\r";
    echo "<tr><td>".$i->number."</td><td>".$i->state."</td><td>".$i->title."</td><td>".$i->body."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Table tag is not there, try this

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP');
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/stroes/stroestest/issues");
$data = json_decode($json); ?>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($data as $i)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$i->number."</td><td>".$i->state."</td><td>".$i->title."</td><td>".$i->body."</td></tr>";
?>
<tr>
    <td> ?>
    <?php echo $i->number ?>.
    </td>
    <td> ?>
    <?php echo $i->state ?>.
    </td>
    <td> ?>
    <?php echo $i->title ?>.
    </td>
    <td> ?>
    <?php echo $i->body ?>.
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: you have placed unwanted `?>` after every `<td>` in last row.also this will repeat a same value twice resulting to create two rows with same values